# How to solve 'java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError' error?

Tags: java, command-prompt

I have been learning java for quite some time now, but recently one of the hard drive of my windows PC was replaced (not the one with operating system on it) ever since Java compiler and interpreter is not working.

I have already updated the JDK file path variable and %JAVA_HOME% variable: -

[This image shows %JAVA_HOME% variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1L4Bu.png)

[This image shows path variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHboS.png)

But when I tried to test Java in command prompt, by typing javac, the follow error comes out: -

```
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
where possible options include:
  @<filename>                  Read options and filenames from file
  -Akey[=value]                Options to pass to annotation processors
  --add-modules <module>(,<module>)*
        Root modules to resolve in addition to the initial modules, or all modules
        on the module path if <module> is ALL-MODULE-PATH.
  --boot-class-path <path>, -bootclasspath <path>
        Override location of bootstrap class files
  --class-path <path>, -classpath <path>, -cp <path>
        Specify where to find user class files and annotation processors
  -d <directory>               Specify where to place generated class files
  -deprecation
        Output source locations where deprecated APIs are used
  --enable-preview
        Enable preview language features. To be used in conjunction with either -source or --release.
  -encoding <encoding>         Specify character encoding used by source files
  -endorseddirs <dirs>         Override location of endorsed standards path
  -extdirs <dirs>              Override location of installed extensions
  -g                           Generate all debugging info
  -g:{lines,vars,source}       Generate only some debugging info
  -g:none                      Generate no debugging info
  -h <directory>
        Specify where to place generated native header files
  --help, -help, -?            Print this help message
  --help-extra, -X             Print help on extra options
  -implicit:{none,class}
        Specify whether or not to generate class files for implicitly referenced files
  -J<flag>                     Pass <flag> directly to the runtime system
  --limit-modules <module>(,<module>)*
        Limit the universe of observable modules
  --module <module>(,<module>)*, -m <module>(,<module>)*
        Compile only the specified module(s), check timestamps
  --module-path <path>, -p <path>
        Specify where to find application modules
  --module-source-path <module-source-path>
        Specify where to find input source files for multiple modules
  --module-version <version>
        Specify version of modules that are being compiled
  -nowarn                      Generate no warnings
  -parameters
        Generate metadata for reflection on method parameters
  -proc:{none,only}
        Control whether annotation processing and/or compilation is done.
  -processor <class1>[,<class2>,<class3>...]
        Names of the annotation processors to run; bypasses default discovery process
  --processor-module-path <path>
        Specify a module path where to find annotation processors
  --processor-path <path>, -processorpath <path>
        Specify where to find annotation processors
  -profile <profile>
        Check that API used is available in the specified profile
  --release <release>
        Compile for the specified Java SE release. Supported releases: 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19
  -s <directory>               Specify where to place generated source files
  --source <release>, -source <release>
        Provide source compatibility with the specified Java SE release. Supported releases: 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19
  --source-path <path>, -sourcepath <path>
        Specify where to find input source files
  --system <jdk>|none          Override location of system modules
  --target <release>, -target <release>
        Generate class files suitable for the specified Java SE release. Supported releases: 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19
  --upgrade-module-path <path>
        Override location of upgradeable modules
  -verbose                     Output messages about what the compiler is doing
  --version, -version          Version information
  -Werror                      Terminate compilation if warnings occur
```

And, when I type in %JAVA_HOME% following shows: -

```
'C:\Java\jdk-19.0.1\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Although when I type in 'java -version' : -

```
java version "19.0.1" 2022-10-18
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 19.0.1+10-21)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0.1+10-21, mixed mode, sharing)
```

this shows up,

Please tell me what to do

Comment: None of the output in the question looks wrong. Is there some other problem that you’re trying to resolve? The exception in the title of the question isn’t mentioned anywhere in the question text. If that’s the actual problem, please include the complete stack trace in the question text.

Comment: "...  when I type in %JAVA_HOME% following shows ...".  As it should!  Your `%JAVA_HOME%` variable **correctly** refers to a directory.  You cannot execute a directory.

Comment: As Tim says, you need to show us the complete stacktrace.  We cannot possibly diagnose your problem from the information included in your question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.